# SQL count instances of column combinations

Tags: sql

I have a query that returns the following table.

| Parent | Child | Grandchild | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | a | xx |
| 1 | B | b | xy |
| 1 | C | c | xy |
| 1 | A | d | xy |
| 1 | D | e | xy |
| 1 | E | f | xx |
| 2 | F | g | xx |

What I want to do is filter this down to just rows where Gender is xx, but ONLY when there are no other grandchildren. If I add "where Gender = 'xx'", I get this:

| Parent | Child | Grandchild | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | a | xx |
| 1 | E | f | xx |
| 2 | F | g | xx |

But I really only want:

| Parent | Child | Grandchild | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | E | f | xx |
| 2 | F | g | xx |

Because (1, A, a, xx) has a grandchild sibling of (1, A, d, xy)

Comment: One way can be to filter out siblings with a subquery and a `WHERE NOT EXISTS (...)`. I would recommend starting with a similar query, make sure it works as expected, then try to optimize _if needed_.

Comment: And, please show the query in your question. (if you have a query ...)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to add a self-join here as an additional condition (for example, using WHERE NOT EXISTS, as suggested in the comment above).

Take a look at how duplicates are removed in SQL using self-joins, this should get you along the way: https://flylib.com/books/en/2.305.1/eliminating_duplicates_from_a_self_join_result.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you want that the *parent*/*child* is not repeated.  You can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by parent, child) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt = 1 and gender = 'xx'
```